# Frequency distribution for radio custom fields / survey / statistics / report

Tags: extension, civireport, core

we have set up a tiny survey with a bunch of custom fields with data type int and a radio controlled option set

```
Value | Label
-------------
 -1   |  No
  0   |  Unknown
  1   |  Yes
```

attached to activities of a specific type.

We're looking for a way to create a statistical evaluation called frequency distributions. The result would sum up the occurences of every option value for a set of fields and display it by label.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_(statistics)#Frequency_distribution_table

I'm not a native english speaker but from my understanding of civicrm docs and code there's is no report template (neither in core nor in ExtendedReports or Report+) and no dataprocessor source/aggeragation field for this popose.

How/where would you implement it?

I thought about a dataprocessor custom group source which serves the data and a new aggregation type. But dataprocessor seems not to allow injecting new source classes from outside it's very own Factory class. And a customized fork maintained by me is'nt what want.

I know I can use drupal 7's view aggregation but I would prefer extending civicrm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody searching for this:
We've developed a tiny extension for this purpose and published under
https://github.com/kompetenzz/net.kompetenzz.freco.
This extension provides API4 and UI to compute frequency distribution across a set of custom fields.